# Where pubish_stream permission?

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I'm making an app for Android. My app capture and save video to facebook. I find a cool library: Simple Facebook: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/. But when I try to publish video it say to me that I must to add permission publish_stream. In Facebook Developers I can't find this permission.

**Edited:**

No error. I simple not found permission.

Comment: adding the actual text/screenshot of the error would help. Also, it makes sense to tag the question with 'android-simple-facebook' tag.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-simple-facebook

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since many years.

Answer (score 0):

In Facebook Developers you must require `publish_actions` permission in order to post something on your behalf. Probably that library is not updated, so it says `publish_stream`.

Comment: "in facebook developers"? what does that even mean?